# How can I update my List loop in my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, lambda

I have a list attached to the datasource of a gridview, when I make the change from my list in the status field I would like to change the status in gridview as well.

My loop is through the datagridview and it is linked in my list, I think the problem is this?

How can I update my List loop in my DataGridView?

MyList

```
List<Dados> SendMsg;
```

Populating Form_Load

```
    SendMsg = GetDados();
    gvSent.DataSource = SendMsg;
```

Event Click

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = gvSent.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (gvSent.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                //defaultDGV.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                long str = unchecked((long)gvSent.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);


                var query = (from send in SendMsg
                             where send.MessageSentId == str
                             select send)
                 .Update(st => { st.Status = "S"; });

                MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
                gvSent.DataSource = query;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is  `SendMsg`? where does it come from?

Comment: @EmilioCeroleni My class Dados e my list List<Dados> SendMsg;

Comment: Ok. So you want to update your list when some value is added or changed in your grid,  right?

Comment: Yes that's right, but I think it will freeze my form when it's in the loop, correct? Then I'll need to implement thread usage.

Comment: I will consume a service on the web that same service returns me if it was successful or failed, when it is successful I need to show STATUS = S for user

Comment: Not at all, you can handle the [`CellEndEdit` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx) and  use the row and cell index to reference rje position in your list.

Answer (score 0):

use a BindingSource

`BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = SendMsg;
yourDataGridView.DataSource = bs;`